# How to add pop up list menu in list icon?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, popup, popupmenu

Please help me out on how to add pop menu list like the picture I attached. I'm quite knew to react native. Please help me out. Below are the codes. I would like to add the pop menu list in member list page. By the way i have imported the icon from headerbar.js.
[Attached Image Of Pop menu list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdGkj.png)

MemberList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { HeaderBar4 } from '../components/HeaderBar';
import {GrayScrollView, EventTitle,SearchBarAlign} from '../components/styles';
import { MemberCell, SearchBarCell } from '../components/MemberInput';

const MemberList = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <GrayScrollView contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <HeaderBar4/>
            <EventTitle>Members List</EventTitle>
            <SearchBarAlign>
            <SearchBarCell/>
            </SearchBarAlign>
            <MemberCell/>
        </GrayScrollView>
        
    );
}

export default MemberList;
```

HeaderBar.js

```
export const HeaderBar4 = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <HeaderBarContainer>
            <LeftBarContainer>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <BackIcon name="arrow-left"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </LeftBarContainer>
            <RightBarContainer>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={undefined}>
                    <CartIcon name="cart-outline" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={undefined}>
                    <BellIcon name="bell" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={undefined}>
                    <SliderIcon name="list"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </RightBarContainer>
        </HeaderBarContainer>
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% I get your question if you are trying to make a pop-up menu you will need to work with the z-index of your component styles or you can use pre-made packages like this [Pop up menu package](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu). If you are interested in making your own component you can follow this article [Link to custom pop up menu article](https://hartaniyassir.medium.com/how-to-create-a-popup-menu-in-react-native-d2fc8908e932)

If you are trying to make circular checkboxes you can use this package. [Link to circular checkbox package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circle-checkbox)

Comment: Thank u for helping me out Mandip, can I have a sample demo of the modified code.

Comment: You can go through the article I have put up in answer to see sample demo or browse through the packages they both provide demo as well